# Getting the cell details in QTableWidget

Tags: qt

I have a QTableWidget in my application. I am adding QPushButton widgets to the cells of the table widget during run time. Now, I need to do some action when this newly added button is clicked. I need to get the row and column details of the cell which contains this button. How can I get these details? I am new to Qt and looking for help.

Thank you,
Rakesh.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the row number of widget placed in a cell of Qtablewidget when it get clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45182348/how-to-get-the-row-number-of-widget-placed-in-a-cell-of-qtablewidget-when-it-get)

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is to utilize Qt's property system and add dynamic row and column property to the button when you insert it. Here's an example.

```
# table_button_11361328.pro
QT       += core gui
TARGET = table_button_11361328
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

```
// main.cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLabel>

class Display : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Display(QWidget* parent = 0) : QLabel(parent) {}
public slots:
    void indicate() {
        QWidget * w = qobject_cast<QWidget*>(sender());
        if (w == 0) return;
        int row = w->property("tableRow").toInt();
        int column = w->property("tableColumn").toInt();
        setText(QString("* %1,%2 *").arg(row).arg(column));
    }
};

QWidget * setWidget(QTableWidget* table, int row, int column, QWidget * w)
{
    w->setProperty("tableRow", row);
    w->setProperty("tableColumn", column);
    table->setCellWidget(row, column, w);
    return w;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTableWidget table;
    Display * d = new Display();
    table.setRowCount(3);
    table.setColumnCount(2);
    table.setCellWidget(2, 0, d);
    d->connect(setWidget(&table, 0, 0, new QPushButton("0,0")), SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(indicate()));
    d->connect(setWidget(&table, 0, 1, new QPushButton("0,1")), SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(indicate()));
    d->connect(setWidget(&table, 1, 0, new QPushButton("1,0")), SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(indicate()));
    d->connect(setWidget(&table, 1, 1, new QPushButton("1,1")), SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(indicate()));
    table.show();
    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Note this will fail if the table is sorted.

Comment: @Constantin It indicates numbers tied to the model index, not tied to the view index. Having something tied to the view is a different problem.

Comment: My point still stands - model location is unnecessary information for a QTableWidget which manages the model for you. This is not an attack on your process, I like it, it's just a note for people who take this route with sorted QTableWidgets.