# How to get the row number of widget placed in a cell of Qtablewidget when it get clicked?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt4.8

[image]

What i'm trying is to get the row number of QcomboBox when user selects items. Although its easy to to get the cell column and row using

```
cellClicked(int,int)
```

signal, but it only works when there is no widget on the cell.

so how to get the row number in case if there is a widget placed in a cell.

**Note:** All the combobox are added dynamically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At-last i found 2 ways of doing it.

1. By setting the property of QComboBox
2. Using the QSignalMapper

**First Method**

```
QComboBox* mCombo = new QCombobox();
mComboBox->setProperty("row",(int) i); // i represents the row number in qtablewidget
```

In handler function where you are handling the clicked QComboBox

```
int row = sender()->property("row").toInt();
```

**Second Method**

```
QSignalMapper *signalMapper= new QSignalMapper(this);   //Create a signal mapper instance 

for (each row in table) {
     QComboBox* mCombo = new QComboBox();
     table->setCellWidget(row,col,combo);                          
     connect(mCombo, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));  

/*connect each signal of QComboBox to signal Mapper slot (i.e map()) which in turns connected to the signal of signalMapper calling the SLOT associated with it (i.e rowFinder) */         

signalMapper->setMapping(combo, (int)row);  //assign mapping to each widgetusing set mapping


}

connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)),
         this, SLOT(rowFinder(int)));
```

function : rowFinder(int rowIndex)

```
int row = rowIndex; //here is the row indexof selected QComboBox
```

Comment: The correct way is to use a QStyledItemDelegate subclass that paints the combobox and creates it as editor. once that is implemented you can use the signals from `table->selectionModel()` (`selectionChanged` and `currentChanged`) to intercept whatever you want (but, again, I'm 99.9999% certain what you are trying to do is already doable inside the delegate)